# how to free managed_shared_memory after a program crash: what are effective techniques to use during debugging?

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

Admittedly I am a novice and self-taught programmer, and am finally venturing into the depths and power of C and C++. Some things that come with this self-learning process are not textbook or overtly googleable knowledge, such as tricks to use in difficult circumstances, and debugging strategies.

I am using boost::interprocess to set up shared memory using the managed_shared_memory and named objects. Unsurprisingly, my program crashes here and there for a number of reasons during my development. So far, I am rather unfamiliar with debugging tools, especially in linux. As a consequence, many times my shared memory does not get removed properly, as the crashing can result in destructors never being called, etc.

So, after such a program crash, when I attempt to run my application again, when my code tires to allocate a new segment of shared memory I see messages like:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
  what():  boost::interprocess_exception::library_error
```

which I understand is the result of the lingering shared memory of the same name that never got closed, and is now rogue. I have tried using the

```
open_or_create
```

flag in my application, in hopes that subsequent instances of my program would reconnect that shared memory, and then I could find/clear the previous objects in the segment, and start over as if it were a fresh run. However, this doesn't happen. My application throws the above error, or hangs, and I can't proceed with subsequent attempts at running my program.

What is an effective way of clearing out shared memory after a crash like this, so that I can run again after editing/rebuilding my application?

Right now, the only thing I can do is to do my best to avoid these crashes. But when crashes do occur, all I know how to do at the moment to run again successfully is to first reboot. Time consuming, and awkward, and certainly short of something optimal a more experienced programmer would do.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Thanks,
B

EDIT:
Is there any specific advice how to proceed with `ipcs` and `ipcrm`?

On a fresh boot, I can run ipcs, then my app, then ipcs a second time (while my app is still open, and shared memory still accessible), and I see no difference in any shared memory segments.

I am allocating memory with a statement that looks like this

```
managed_shared_memory segment(open_or_create, "sharedMemtest", 1048588)
```

Comment: On *nix systems, I would try the `ipcs` and `ipcrm` commands.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. You are writing C++.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks, I'll look into those

Comment: @AlanStokes, thanks :-/ yes I am aware C/C++ is not a single language, i never claimed it was. I had written these two with a slash as is commonly used to group the likes of them together. For your reading pleasure, I have edited my question and replaced the slash with 'and'

Comment: @AlanStokes you're reaching--he neither claimed 'C/C++' was a language nor that he was programming in it; he simply was giving background for his question and using it as shorthand for 'C and C++'. if you pay more attention next time you might note that he correctly tagged the question with 'c++', anyway

Comment: You may want to look into signal handlers; you can write a handler that releases the shared memory and then calls `shared_memory_object::remove`, but you'll want to do a bit of reading about signal handlers because you have to be careful what you do in them. Bear in mind that you may not be the only process accessing the shared memory and you crashing doesn't automatically mean the sharees went away.

Comment: @user3386109 the only reference I can find in regard to getting shmid from boost::interprocess is for XSI shared memory, please check the edits I'm about to make on my original question, and if you have any further input, I'd appreciate hearing them

Comment: @user3386109, do you have any more specific advice for using ipcs and ipcrm in my specific case? See my first EDIT in the original question for where I am currently at with this problem.

Comment: @kfsone you are absolutely correct that I need to learn about signal handlers. But is this the best option for debugging a developing project, to set up clean-up functions in signal handlers that might not be relevant in the long run with a finalized application? Is there any signal handling specifically integrated in any worthwhile debugging tools/ide that I should check out?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any additional advice. If the `ipcs` command doesn't show the shared memory when the app is still running, then `ipcrm` is not useful.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
 shared_memory_object::remove("sharedMemtest");
```

before your

```
managed_shared_memory segment(open_or_create, "sharedMemtest", 1048588);
```

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: may use construct function when open a shm; 1. use remove  2. segement find_or_construct instead of construct function

Comment: It just a feedback of how you answered the question. Try and edit your question to add all the details that the SO might need. Try and review before: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer